# UnsatisfiableError with conda for fiona

Tags: python, anaconda, geospatial

I am using `conda` with Intel's Python to chart some data, and when I go to install fiona, I get this error:

```
$ conda install -f fiona
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ....
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - fiona
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Here is my Python:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12 :: Intel Corporation
```

What was found in conflict and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Sometimes it is tough to solve the conflict in existing python environment. Use conda to create new environment, and install fiona first in that environment.